# jmap not working on windows server 2003

Tags: memory-leaks, jvm, heap-memory

jmap works fine for me on XP. But when I try to execute the command, it throws and error

Not enough storage available to process.

I used the following command

jmap -dump:format=b,file=heap1.bin .

Note that tomcat is running as a service on windows server.

I tried the same on windows xp and no problems there.

Any ideas??

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

if you're doing this over RDP, you might need to RDP into the machine as /console or /admin, i.e.

```
mstsc /admin
```

or

```
mstsc /console
```

On one windows 2003 server, I needed to use `mstsc /admin`; on another, `mstsc /console` worked fine.

Answer (score 1):

connecting with a console session resolved this

Answer (score 0):

I was having similar error on win2k3 machine, which I solved by using:

```
mstsc /admin /v:<hostname>
```